# Emulator Network Issues

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am developing an app that makes web requests.

I have a windows phone 8 device which I use for debugging and it is connected straight to my office's wifi network. The web requests go through perfectly fine when debugging using device.

My laptop is connected to the same wifi service, but when debugging using the emulator the web requests always fails. The internet explorer in the emulator also isn't showing pages.

Does anyone know what is wrong and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [Troubleshooting the Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681694(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_CannotconnecttoInternetdestinations) on MSDN and let us know if it helps you.